# Creating a SQL database script for fictional restaurant

Tags: sql, database

im making a fictional database for a ficitonal restaurant. I managed to write most of SQL script myself and it works. Like creating tables, inserting fake data. However I am not sure how to connect a meal to an order and table, and bill to a meal, and all of that to a customer.

Here is my script (the commented out foreign keys are what i dont know how to connect, or how to edit them so its all connected as i mentioned above):

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS restaurantDB;
CREATE DATABASE restaurantDB;
USE restaurantDB;

CREATE TABLE `bill`  (
  `billID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `payAmount` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`billID`)
);

INSERT INTO `bill` VALUES (1, '$258');

CREATE TABLE `customer`  (
  `customerID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerID`)
);

INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES (1, 'Bruce', 'Lee', '420420589');

CREATE TABLE `meal`  (
  `mealID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sides` varchar(255) NULL,
  `main` varchar(255) NULL,
  `beverage` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mealID`)
);

INSERT INTO `meal` VALUES (1, 'potatos', 'steak', 'wine');

CREATE TABLE `order`  (
  `orderID` int NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime(2) NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderID`)
);

INSERT INTO `order` VALUES (1, '21-09-27 13:36:06');

CREATE TABLE `reservation`  (
  `reservationID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `checkIn` datetime(2) NOT NULL,
  `checkOut` datetime(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reservationID`)
);

INSERT INTO `reservation` VALUES (1, '21-09-27 13:24:06', '21-09-27 14:17:23');

CREATE TABLE `table`  (
  `tableID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `numOfSeats` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tableID`)
);

INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (1, 1);

/* ALTER TABLE `table` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_bill_table_1` FOREIGN KEY (`tableID`) REFERENCES `table` (`billID`);
ALTER TABLE `order` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_order_table_1` FOREIGN KEY (`orderID`) REFERENCES `table` (`tableID`);
ALTER TABLE `order` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_order_meal_1` FOREIGN KEY (`orderID`) REFERENCES `meal` (`mealID`);
ALTER TABLE `order` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_order_bill_1` FOREIGN KEY (`orderID`) REFERENCES `bill` (`billID`);
ALTER TABLE `reservation` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_reservation_customer_1` FOREIGN KEY (`reservationID`) REFERENCES `customer` (`customerID`);
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_table_reservation_1` FOREIGN KEY (`tableID`) REFERENCES `reservation` (`reservationID`); */
```

Here is also a picture of the diagram (not sure if it makes sense connected like i have it currently tho):
[image]

Thanks to anyone who will be able to explain and help make the connections.

Comment: Would you mind sketching that for me? I am trying to sketch it myself but im not sure if i understand you correctly. Also Ive mentioned that im not sure which foreign keys should go where. So Id be glad if I could see that from you as well. I am grateful for your comments. I do think, I understand but im not so confident since ive just started learning this haha

Comment: @Austin I managed to make most relations, but one is throwing me this error: #1067 - Invalid default value for 'time'... Its this one `order` table.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Should an order have a single menu or multiple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so finally got it working. Thanks @Austin.
Actually the only issue I had was with the datetime(2) it was just supposed to say datetime.

However @Austin showed me a better alternative, so I will create also a second, extended database with the relations @Austin suggested and add onto that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).